# Activity feed not showing records by using public activity gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, public-activity

I want to display my activity feed for absences on my dashboard page. I am using public activity gem.

In my modal I have added

**absence.rb**

```
 class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :amendments
 end
```

I want activity feed for amendments

In my controller

```
 class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @user = User.new(params[:id])
   if user_signed_in?
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
    redirect_to dashboard_users_path
   else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
   end
  end
 end
```

In my view

```
  %h1 Activity Feed
  - @activities.each do |activity|
    = activity.inspect
```

But this is giving me Undefined method each for nil:Nil class. I am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast   Why am i getting such an error?

Answer (score 1):

you added to the application controller is: 
`include PublicActivity::StoreController`

Comment: The basic details are not shown either and I have added the line in controller but the issue still persists